# Clickhouse Null table engine not incrementing AggregatingMergeTree correctly on cluster

Tags: clickhouse

ClickHouse version I using: 22.11-alpine

I use `Null` table engine in my project as temp table from which data will be sent to `ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree`.

This described test case indicates problem:

```
CREATE TABLE default.data ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
(
    id Int8,
    group_by String,
    value Int8
)
ENGINE = Null;

CREATE TABLE default.data_agg ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
(
    group_by String,
    value AggregateFunction(sum, Int8)
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY group_by;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW default.data_agg_mv ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
TO default.data_agg AS
SELECT
    group_by,
    sumState(value) as value
FROM default.data
GROUP BY group_by;

CREATE TABLE default.data_agg_dis ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
AS default.data_agg
ENGINE = Distributed('{cluster}', default, data_agg, rand());
```

All that schemas are created on the cluster (ClickHouse Keeper), with 4 nodes, 4 shards, and 2 replicas.

Problem:

```
INSERT INTO default.data VALUES (1, 'group1', 1);
```

Above insert query at first-time increments value in `data_agg_dis` correctly:

```
SELECT group_by, sumMerge(value) as value FROM default.data_agg_dis GROUP BY group_by;

Results:
group_by | value
group1   |   1
```

But when I try to repeat mentioned insert value for `group_by: group1`, `value` reaches just up to `value: 4`. Feels like that when all shards touch all other aggregates are skipped.

But if I change `group_by: group1` value in insert query from 1 to 2:

```
    INSERT INTO default.data VALUES (1, 'group1', 2);
```

again in `data_agg_dis` value increments by 2, four times and stops. This behavior is reproducible just on cluster on a single node ClickHouse server all works as espected.

Does anybody aware of same issue? it is some limitation of ClickHouse cluster? or bug?

Comment: it's a feature not a bug https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-schema-design/insert_deduplication/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree` just apply deduplication by block cause you try to INSERT the same data.

Look to https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-insert-deduplicate for details.